# How Can I Press/Send Right Ctrl Key using QTP/VBA?

Tags: vbscript, qtp, ctrl

I need to automate 1 system where 1 step is to press right ctrl key (left ctrl key doesn't work).

I have already tried sendkeys method but its not working.

Is there any other way to send/press right ctrl key in VB Script?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet of what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I used DeviceReplay.

Here is the piece of code..

```
Set DeviceReplay = CreateObject("Mercury.DeviceReplay")

DeviceReplay.PressKey 157
```

we need to send Asc code as parameter of Presskeys. (157 is asc code)

Further info on [finding asc code for other keystrokes](http://www.joecolantonio.com/2011/07/19/qtp-secret-code-chart-revealed-for-devicereplay-presskey-keydown-keyup-and-pressnkeys/).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `autoit`?

https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/appendix/SendKeys.htm

`{RCTRL}` for right ctrl

`{LCTRL}` for left ctrl

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to accomplish this using the QTP tool as far as I know. But you can resort to pure VBscript (outside QTP) and use another tool.

Edit: Wow. I stand corrected.